# Information Retrieval: no merge/ immediate merge strategies in incremental/semi-static indexes

Tags: web, documents, search-indexing, ir

I wonder if someone knows what no merge and immediate merge strategies are when used in incremental (supports only inserts), semi-static (supports only inserts + deletions) or dynamic indexes (supports inserts, deletions and updates). Also applies to in-place and hybrid strategy.

I am looking for an explanation of the main concept and differences of the application of those strategies in different index types.

If you are asking how I even found out about the existence of those topics, I am currently in an information retrieval module in my Uni, but i did not fully understand those concepts from the lecture. I would ask my professor about this, but the exam is soon and it usually takes a long time before answering there.

Thanks :)

Comment: removed question for sources, instead for information directly. Hope i can get answers now... :(